# SQL query for students mark functionality in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join

There are 3 tables

1. Students(student_id, st_name)
2. Subjects(subject_id,sub_name)
3. Marks(st_id,sub_id,Score)

Write an SQL query to display the student name, average score of the student, maximum mark obtained by the student , name of the subject in which the student has scored maximum marks.

Below is the code I wrote

I am getting the errors -Column 'students.name' and 'subjects.name' are invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
select students.st_name as Students_Name,avg(Score) as Average, max(Score) as Maximum,subjects.sub_name as Max_Subject_name  
from marks 
join students on students.student_id=marks.st_id
join subjects on subjects.subject_id=marks.sub_id
join
(
select st_id,avg(score) as Average,max(score) as Maximum from  marks group by st_id
) as x  on x.st_id=marks.st_id
order by students.st_name,subjects.sub_name;
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am getting the errors -Column 'students.name' and 'subjects.name' are invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: [edit] the error to your question

Comment: Your join to subjects is incorrect. And now would be a good time to review best practices for writing tsql code and start developing GOOD coding habits. Among others - don't cram your code together - a little whitespace and indentation would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
;with cte as
(
select students.st_name as Students_Name
,students.student_id
      ,RANK() over(partition by students.student_id  order by marks.score desc) as seq
      ,subjects.sub_name as Max_Subject_name  
      ,Marks.Score
from marks 
INNER join students 
    on students.student_id=marks.st_id
INNER join subjects 
    on subjects.subject_id=marks.sub_id
)
select 
Students_Name
,student_id
,Max_Subject_name
,Score
,(select avg(score) from cte b where b.student_id=a.student_id) as average
from cte a
where seq=1
```

Comment: This is correct!!!   Can we add an extra column to display the average marks of the student as well?

Comment: edited to include average

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select students.name as Students_Name
      ,avg(Score) as Average
      ,max(Score) as Maximum
      ,subjects.name as Max_Subject_name  
from marks 
INNER join students 
    on students.student_id=marks.st_id
INNER join subjects 
    on subjects.subject_id=marks.st_id
GROUP BY students.name
        ,subjects.name
order by students.name
        ,subjects.name;
```

or if you want your query:

```
select students.name as Students_Name,x.Average, x.Maximum,subjects.name as Max_Subject_name  
from marks 
join students on students.student_id=marks.st_id
join subjects on subjects.subject_id=marks.st_id
join
(
select st_id,avg(score) as Average,max(score) as Maximum from  marks group by st_id
) as x  on x.st_id=marks.st_id
order by students.name,subjects.name;
```

Comment: The above query is showing the subject name having maximum marks according to the student id which is unexpected . We need the subject name having maximum marks based on the subject id. In other words we have to print the names of subjects which has the maximum marks for each student.